# How to read certain lines of a csv by a string and empty line?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read CSV files that has columns stacked on top of each other. They look something like this:

```
Body 1
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3

Body 2
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
Data_Col_1 Data_Col_2 Data_Col_3
```

I'm trying to write a function that will start reading the csv file after a certain string (e.g. Body 2) and stop once it encounters a blank line.

My code looks like this:

```
def csv_strings(filepath, bl_group_n=1, start=str, dtype=str):
with open(filepath, newline='') as f:
    blank_lines = 0
    bl_groups = 0
    contents = []
    headers = None
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if not row:
            break
        else:
            if bl_groups < bl_group_n:
                if start in row:
                    blank_lines += 1
                    continue
                if blank_lines == 0:
                    continue
                bl_groups += 1
                blank_lines = 0
                headers = row
                continue
            contents.append(row)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=contents, columns=headers, dtype=dtype)
```

The first portion works fine. I'm able to start reading the csv at the desired line that contains the start string.

The problem is that it doesn't stop once it's encountered the blank line.

So far I've tried:

```
if row == '\n'

if row == ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
# I printed all the rows to see what an empty line looked like in my csv files.

if row == '\r\n'
```

An example of the error is below. The csv is supposed to stop at row 28, but continues.

[image]

EDIT 1:

So I made some changes that were suggested. I had to use isinstance() instead of isType() because for some reason Python wasn't recognizing the latter as a function. I also created a dummy row called row2 to check the emptiness since I didn't want to change row as it is also used in the else statement underneath.

Now, the output is just a dash which is an empty data frame. Does this mean that every row has some white space?

[image]

EDIT 2:

I don't know how to add an example csv file to my post.

Due to confidentiality issues, I can't post the real data. However, I have a mock up that is in a similar format.

My files look something like this:

[image]

What I want is for my code to be able to extract certain lines.

For example, if I ran

```
test = csv_strings(filepath = '/Users/mi-okkim/Desktop/Dummy Data.csv', bl_group_n=1, start='Activities', dtype=str)
```

My output is

[image]

But I want it to be

[image]

Essentially, I want it to stop once it's read that the next row is blank.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  As screen shot of a program segment does us very little good in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

What you failed to check is what you actually have for a "blank row".  Obviously, it is *not* any of the possibilities for which you tested.  If you want to use some straightforward overkill:

- Ensure that `row` is a single string
- Strip out whitespace
- Compare the result to an empty string

Possible code:

```
if isType(row, list):   #If it's a list, join the fields into a single string
    row = ''.join(row)

if not row.strip(" \n\r\t"):
    break
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code but now it's just outputting an empty data frame. Does this mean that every row in my csv file has white space? But if that were the case, shouldn't the remaining strings remain that I didn't strip away?